# Internet Explorer gives error: ')' is expected, while firefox isn't?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, model-view-controller

Internet Explorer gives an error ')' is expected while Firefox is running this code fine. According to the Internet Explorer console the error is situated in the first line:

function HTMLtableRows (titles=[] , values=[]) {

How can I fix this problem?

```js
function HTMLtableRows (titles=[] , values=[]) {

            var i, j;
            var str, strT, strM;
            str = '<table class="table">';

            str = str + '<tr>';
            for (j = 0; j < titles.length; j++) {
                str = str + '<th colspan="2"><center>' + titles[j] + '</center></th>';
            }
            str = str + '</tr>' + '<tr>';
            for (j = 0; j < titles.length; j++) {
                str = str + '<th>Tijdstip</th>' + '<th>Looptijd</th>';
            }
            str = str + '</tr>' + '<tr>';
            for (j = 0; j < titles.length; j++) {
                var a = values[j].split('\r');
                strT = ''
                strM = ''
                for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                    var b = a[i].split('=');
                    if (b[1] != undefined) {
                        strT = strT + b[0];
                        strM = strM + b[1] + 'min';
                    }
                    if (i < a.length - 1) {
                        strT = strT + '<br>';
                        strM = strM + '<br>';
                    }
                }
                str = str + '<td>' + strT + '</td>';
                str = str + '<td>' + strM + '</td>';
            }
            str = str + '</tr>';

            str = str + '</table>';

            return str;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IE does not support default parameters.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility)

Just do it like this if you want

```js
function HTMLtableRows (titles , values) {
  if (!titles) titles = []; 
  if (!values) values = [];
  
  console.log(titles);
  console.log(values);
}

a1 = [1,2,3];

HTMLtableRows(a1, null);
HTMLtableRows({foo: "bar"}, undefined);
HTMLtableRows(2, NaN);
HTMLtableRows("not empty string", "");
HTMLtableRows(1, 0);
HTMLtableRows(true, false);
```

All of the following values

- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`
- `""`
- `0`
- `false`

will become an empty array. If you don't want some of those values to be overwritten with an empty array adjust `if` conditions as you see fit.

**Example** where you allow `values` to remain unchanged as `""`, `0` and `NaN`:

```js
function HTMLtableRows (titles , values) {

  if (!titles) titles = []; 
  if(values != "" && 
     values != 0  && 
     !isNaN(parseInt(values))
    )
    values = [];
  
  console.log(titles);
  console.log(values);
}

HTMLtableRows("string", "");
HTMLtableRows(1, 0);
HTMLtableRows(7, NaN);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want `if (titles == undefined) titles = [];` ?

Comment: Does this adjustment prevent losing the data that was passed when the function was called?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to alex i've solved this with the adjustments below:

```js
function HTMLtableRows (tmpTitles , tmpValues) {
  titles=[]; 
  values=[];
  titles = tmpTitles;
  values = tmpValues;
  //...
}
```

Comment: Don't do this because this changes nothing. If you want this temporary-parameters approach than do something like this: `titles = tmpTitles ? tmpTitles : [];` and `values = tmpValues ? tmpValues : [];`